# VBA Copy Paste Last Column Formulas & Format in to new column then Copy&Paste Values of new 2nd to last Column

Tags: excel, vba

trying to get a macro that will find the last column with value on row 1 then copy and paste that column with formulas and formatting into new column.  Then when that is done copy and past the original column with values only.

Example

Column "C" "C0A001 Copied and pasted into new Column "D" (NOW C0A002)then Column C will be made into values only.  With D now having formulas.

[image]

Here is what I have so far

```
Sub FS_NewShipment()
'
' FS_NewShipment Macro
' Create new Shipment
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+S
'
Dim LC As Long
LC = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Columns(LC).Copy
Cells(1, LC + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
End Sub
```

Comment: This is as far as I have gotten, totally new to VBA!

Comment: Sub FS_NewShipment()
' FS_NewShipment Macro
' Create new Shipment
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+S
'
Dim LC As Long
LC = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Columns(LC).Copy
Cells(1, LC + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
End Sub

Comment: Added, let me know if it makes sense. Thanks for the help!